# How can we open minicom from current terminal and pass multiple commands to execute and exit to 1st terminal using shell script

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to write a shell script that creates a new window and run a minicom terminal (connected to /dev/ttyACM0) in that.
Here's the script file my_script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal --command minicom
echo "\n" >> /dev/ttyACM0
sleep 5
echo "\n" >> /dev/ttyACM0
echo "run x_boot" >> /dev/ttyACM0
sleep 5
echo "root" >> /dev/ttyACM0
sleep 3
echo "cd /tmp" >> /dev/ttyACM0
sleep 1
```

In the above code all the echo commands i'm passing directly to the device file not to the minicom terminal.

Requirements:

1. Now I need to send command1 to minicom
2. Make the terminal to sleep for 5 sec before sending next command
3. Send Command2
4. Wait again for 5sec.
5. And many commands automated
6. After that exit the terminal without closing minicom

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use minicom scripting (runscript) instead of bash echoes. It has both send and sleep commands:

```
-S, --script=SCRIPT    : run SCRIPT at startup
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I found it yesterday and my code is working fine.

Comment: digging out on this question: Is it possible to launch minicom with -S and exit minicom after script is executed, with the exit code given by the script?